# JS or Prototype: Break string into two variables

Tags: javascript, string, prototypejs

Say I have a load of strings that follow the same sort of structure as this:

```
Outcome 1: - Be able to create 2D animations for use as part of an interactive media product.
```

I want to get everything before the '-' and put it into one variable, and everything after the '-' and put it into another variable. So output is as so:

```
$1 = "Outcome 1";
$2 = "Be able to create 2D animations for use as part of an interactive media product.";
```

Thanks

(Also does anyone know how I would then remove the title tag from the following selector?

```
  $$('span[title]').each(function(element) {
});
```

Comment: Please try not to ask two distinct questions in one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split a string using regular expressions. In your case, you want to:

1. Get rid of the colon (:)
2. Get rid of the extra space surrounding the dash (-)

So:

```
var tokens = s.split(/:\s*-\s*/);
// tokens[0] will be the first part
// tokens[1] the second
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "Outcome 1: - Be able to create 2D animations for use as part of an interactive media product."

var strArr = string.split("-");
```

RESULTS:

```
strArr[0] == "Outcome 1: "
strArr[1] == " Be able to create 2D animations for use as part of an interactive media product."
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/VqcPJ/

Comment: Not complete. Need to trim the colon and extra spaces.

Comment: @AtesGoral, the OP never stated that.

Comment: please pay attention to the part that starts with "So output is as so".

Comment: @AtesGoral -- i quote `I want to get everything before the '-' and put it into one variable, and everything after the '-' and put it into another variable.`

Comment: This should work with `string.split(": - ");`, I believe, if you don't want to do regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will remove the trailing colon on the first element and any whitespace surrounding the dash as well:

```
var parts = str.split(/\s*:\s*-\s*/);
parts; // => ['Outcome 1', 'Be able to create...']
```